# Trying to write a SQL group by statement to group all dispatched data relating to all dates greater than a given date

Tags: sql, date

I have written a block of SQL code pulling out item codes and dispatch quantities by store number, for all dates greater than a given date.

I have tried to group by date, item code and store number, however it is not producing the results I am looking for.

``
I have written the below code:

```
SELECT
HYB.BTC_ITEM_CODE
,STORE_NO
,SUM(DISPATCHED_QTY) AS DISPATCHED_QTY
,CAST(DISPATCH_DATE AS DATE) AS DISPATCH_DATE
FROM srmi.FACT_HYBRID_DISPATCHES_DLY AS MFC

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
    BTC_ITEM_CODE
    ,SAP_ITEM_CODE
    FROM scdm.DIM_SAP_TO_BTC_ITEM_CODE
    ) AS HYB
ON MFC.SAP_ITEM_CODE = HYB.SAP_ITEM_CODE

WHERE CAST(DISPATCH_DATE AS DATE) > '2022-10-30'
AND BTC_ITEM_CODE = '8355010'
AND STORE_NO = 2227

GROUP BY CAST(DISPATCH_DATE AS DATE), BTC_ITEM_CODE, STORE_NO
```

Which produces the following table:

| BTC_ITEM_CODE | STORE_NO | DISPATCHED_QTY | DISPATCH_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 17 | 11/1/2022 |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 10 | 11/2/2022 |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 9 | 11/3/2022 |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 19 | 11/5/2022 |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 21 | 11/6/2022 |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 21 | 11/7/2022 |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 16 | 11/8/2022 |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 1 | 11/9/2022 |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 18 | 11/10/2022 |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 51 | 11/11/2022 |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 15 | 11/12/2022 |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 8 | 11/15/2022 |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 41 | 11/16/2022 |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 12 | 11/17/2022 |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 19 | 11/18/2022 |
| 8355010 | 2227 | 1 | 11/21/2022 |

What I was actually looking for was 1 line in the table that looked something like this:

BTC_ITEM_CODE   STORE_NO    DISPATCHED_QTY
8355010           2227               279

I understand to get rid of the DISPATCH_DATE column I need to remove this from the SELECT statement, I have just added this in to show that my code is exploding out by day.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your question completely, but you'll have to remove the `DISPATCH_DATE` from the `GROUP BY` as well...not just the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Don't group by date. That will give you a row for every unique date.